# Haskell - how to generate permutations

Tags: haskell, permutation

How can I create a function which lazily makes permutations for the chars '_' and '*' like this:

For example:

```
Main> function 3
["___","*__","_*_","__*","**_","_**","*_*","***"]
```

First element is made only from `_`, the next 3 are permutations that lists: `*__`, the second 3 are permutations that lists `**_`, and the last element contains only `*`.

How can I do that?

Comment: is this homework? what have you tried?

Comment: this should not be called a "permutation"

Comment: @rotskoff: Permutation means the number of ways you can order the 3 balls. The number of permutations of 3 balls is 6. What you are asking about is completely unrelated. You are not always choosing 3 *'s (sometimes you are choosing 0, 1, or 2). And you also are not distinguishing between the different *'s (which means there is no order; which is the essence of permutations).

Answer (score 4):

Here's another "correct order" version:

```
function :: Int -> [String]
function c = concatMap helper $ zip (reverse [0..c]) [0..c]

helper :: (Int, Int) -> [String]
helper (c,            0)          = [replicate c '_']
helper (0,            c)          = [replicate c '*']
helper (cUnderscores, cAsterisks) = map ('_' :) (helper (cUnderscores - 1, cAsterisks))
                                 ++ map ('*' :) (helper (cUnderscores, cAsterisks - 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at `replicateM`.

Comment: While correct, this is not very helpful, even as a hint.  Most people don't get this trick unless you spell it out for them the first time.  At least mention that it requires the list monad specifically.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I didn't want to spell it out too completely as the actual complete answer had already been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
let k = ["_", "*"]
let p = [ a ++ b ++ c | a <- k, b <- k, c <- k ]
```

Comment: I thought about loose function, for any number. But I found something like that

    replicateM 3 "_*"

But firstly you have to import Control.Monad

Comment: @SzymonSkrzyński Since `replicateM k foo` is `sequence $ replicate k foo`, you can do that without importing `Control.Monad`. The building blocks are available from the `Prelude`. But that doesn't give the desired order, if that's important to you.

Answer (score 0):

The “correct order” version:

```
import Data.List

function k = concatMap (nub . permutations . pat) [0..k]
  where pat x = replicate x '*' ++ replicate (k-x) '_'
```

I don’t know how to step from one permutation to another in constant time, though.